# How to use the yammer embedFeed in a different language than english

Tags: multilingual, yammer

A user can select the language for the yammer website, but how can I make the yam.platform.EmbedFeed use a language other than english?

Answer (score 0):

We only support English for Embedfeed now.  But there is plan in the product roadmap to support other languages, unfortunately, there is no guarantee timeframe yet.